# C++ array of unsigned char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to understand how to create & handle an array of unsigned char arrays in C++. Such as:

```
Array[0] = { new array of unsigned chars }
Array[1] = { new array of unsigned chars }
Array[2] = { new array of unsigned chars }
....and so on
```

I've written the next code but I have the feeling that I'm doing something wrong. The code works correctly, but I don't know if the way I declare the "buffer" and how I delete the cache is the correct way, or if it can produce a memory leak.

```
#define MAX_BUFFER 10

unsigned char* cache[MAX_BUFFER];
bool cache_full = false;

void AddToCache(unsigned char *buffer, const size_t buffer_size)
{
    if (cache_full == true)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < MAX_BUFFER; index++)
    {
        if (cache[index] == NULL)
        {
            cache[index] = new unsigned char[buffer_size];
            memcpy(cache[index], buffer, buffer_size);
        }

        if (index < MAX_BUFFER - 1)
        {
            cache_full = true;
        }
    }
}

void ClearCache()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < MAX_BUFFER; index++)
    {
        if (cache[index] != NULL)
        {
            delete[] cache[index];
            cache[index] = NULL;
        }
    }

    cache_full = false;
}

bool IsCacheFull()
{
    return cache_full;
}
```

Comment: Your memcpy statement is always initializing the same location, but I suspect you want to initialize cache[index].

Comment: You've marked your question C++ but are using C arrays; is there a reason you can't use the STL to 'ease' your pain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works?

```
memcpy(cache, buffer, buffer_size);
```

It shouldn't. That's overwriting all the pointers in `cache` with the contents of `buffer`. In context, this should probably be:

```
memcpy(cache[index], buffer, buffer_size);
```

Also, you'll be setting `cache_full` to `true`, repeatedly, every time you add to the cache.  Try:

```
AddToCache(unsigned char *buffer, const size_t buffer_size)  
{
  for (int index = 0; index < MAX_BUFFER; index++)
  {
    if (cache[index] == NULL)
    {
        cache[index] = new unsigned char[buffer_size];
        memcpy(cache[index], buffer, buffer_size);
        return(index);  // in case you want to find it again
    }
  }

  // if we get here, we didn't find an empty space
  cache_full = true;
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code with all your notes. Yet I'm still unsure that the way I declare the cache variable is correct or not. As this is an array of arrays.

Comment: It's fine. It's an array of pointers-to-unsigned-char, which is what you're allocating and adding to the array.